ScrollY issue in Datatable
I am using Datatable to give style to my table in HTML and I had to enable the ScrollY.
Although It worked, it has a style problem that I am trying to solve.
When you resize the window, for some reason, the header of the table doesn't resize with the table itself.
I had some research and I found out when the web page is ready,it creates this tags related to the table:
<div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 1632px; padding-right: 0px;">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped cell-border table-bord dataTable no-footer" style="width: 1632px; margin-left: 0px;">


My original table still exists, but It creates these tags to do some things.

I tried give to my table a style ="width:100%", but this created tags don't change with my table.
I also tried to change it through JS using the class as reference and directly in css using the class as reference but it didn't work.
I tried to use tableMain.columns.adjust().draw(), didn't work.
Only when you inspect the page and change it through the page you can solve it.

HTML:
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <table id="tbMain" class="table table-hover table-striped cell-border table-bord" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th rowspan="2">COLUMN 1</th>
                    <th rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th rowspan="2">COLUMN 2</th>
                    <th colspan="1">COLUMN 3</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">COLUMN 4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>COLUMN 5</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

JS:
let tableMain = $('#tbMain').DataTable({
        'scrollY': '400px',
        'scrollCollapse': true,
        'responsive': true,
        'ordering': false,
        'order': [1, 'asc'],
        'columns': [
            {width: '5%', className: 'text-center'},
            {width: '5%', className: 'text-center'},
            {width: '30%', className: 'text-center'},
            {width: '40%', className: 'text-center'},
            {width: '10%', className: 'text-center'},
            {width: '10%', className: 'text-center'}
        ],
        'buttons': []
        }
    });
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");

I used Bootstrap 3.3.6 and Datatable 1.11.5.
I hope you can help me.
